# Input Impedance of a diode connected MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, resistance, input, input-impedance

I was trying to derive the small-signal input impedance of a diode-connected MOSFET (figure included), and came up with this expression.

Is my method correct? I have been reading about methods of deriving the input and output impedances using a test voltage, and that is the method I have followed myself.

Some validation on the approach and the answer would help.

[image]

This is my solution.

[image]

Comment: Why is Rd there? What is it. Why is Rd in series in the first schematic but then to ground in the small signal model. That does not make sense.

Comment: Well, in the small signal model, we ground all DC voltages, right? VDD is a DC volatge, so grounding it basically makes Rd connected to the ground, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I should have mentioned that VDD is a DC voltage.

Comment: So, Rd is just a resistor, used to control the DC current of the MOSFET.

Comment: The first schematic does show a VDD.

Comment: I want to calculate the imdedance looking into the source.

Comment: The circuit is taken from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ox4vRCMlGw

This video demonstrates how to compute the output impedance of this same circuit. I wanted to check my learning by calculating the input impedance for that matter and verifying whether I have understood things right.

Comment: Fiar point, I wasn't looking well enough. I suggest that you start with the small signal impedance of a diode connected NMOS to ground biased at a certain current. Calculate the impedance of that. Then the total for your schematic is simply Rd in parallel with that impedance.

Comment: Okay, but is my method correct?

Comment: That is to say, is it free of any technical errors? I found this technique (of using a test voltage) convenient, so it would be really helpful if you tell me whether this is alright or not.

Comment: I am not used to that Vt method and find it confusing and counter intuitive as it seems to add complexity. In the 2nd line you calculate Vd from Vgs * gm * Rd and that ignores the local feedback of connecting the gate to drain. Try replacing Rd with a DC current source first. You should end up at Zin = 1/gm

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. Vt is constant so should be suppressed for small signal. The impedance should be 1/Gm in parallel with Rd.

Comment: @SteveHubbard He wants to calculate the impedance in the source, so that is \$1/g_m+R_D\$, not in parallel. VT is a "test" source to set up the equations.

Comment: This assumes that your model is good at that operating point. At low drain voltage the parallel resistance is low. Look at Id vs Vd curve

Comment: @SvenB I should have looked more closely. I thought Vt represented the threshold voltage but as you say it is the test source. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

[edit] To avoid confusion, from the comments you state that you want to find the impedance looking into the **source**. In other words, this situation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f30t92.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I could find a few mistakes:

- In the third step, you missed an \$R_D\$:

$$
v_D = \frac{g_mR_D}{1+g_mR_D}V_T
$$

- You also made an additional mistake in the second-last step. But it is irrelevant because of the first mistake.

The expression should resolve to:

$$
I_D = g_m\left(\frac{g_mR_D}{1+g_mR_D}-1\right)V_T
$$

- Then another mistake is that by your voltage/current convention, the impedance will be

$$
Z = -\frac{V_T}{I_D}
$$

Don't forget the minus sign.

---

The result with these corrections will be:

$$Z = \frac{1}{g_m} + R_D$$

As expected. A diode-connected transistor has an approximate impedance of \$1/g_m\$ which is in series with \$R_D\$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But, why should Z be equal to the negative of the voltage to current ratio?

Comment: I think that 1/gm is **in parallel** with Rd so that would make your formula for Z incorrect! This might be due to the drawing, I was also confused thinking that Rd and /1gm are in series. They're not, the top of Rd is connected to Vdd.

Comment: @Curiosity That is because the impedance is the voltage across the nodes divided by the current flowing *in* the circuit. You defined the current as flowing *out* of the circuit.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The author states in the comments that he tries to find the impedances looking into the source. This makes the transistor and resistor in series to AC ground.

Comment: I see no mention of "looking into the source". OK, it's in the comments, then the schematic doesn't match. **What a mess!!** (the question, not your answer) All-in-all OP should be more clear on what he wants as now all of us are making assumptions. Literally: "derive the small-signal input impedance of a diode-connected MOSFET" and then the answer would be 1/gm. OP introduces the Rd resistor and complicates everything.